# Creating objects from Primitive avro schema

Tags: java, avro, spark-avro, jackson-dataformat-avro

Suppose I have a schema in avro like this

```
{ "type" : "string" }
```

How should i create object from this schema in java?

Answer (score 1):

I did not found a way to do it directly with the java avro lib

but you can still do this

```
  public static byte[] jsonToAvro(String json, Schema schema) throws IOException {
    DatumReader<Object> reader = new GenericDatumReader<>(schema);
    GenericDatumWriter<Object> writer = new GenericDatumWriter<>(schema);
    ByteArrayOutputStream output = new ByteArrayOutputStream();
    Decoder decoder = DecoderFactory.get().jsonDecoder(schema, json);
    Encoder encoder = EncoderFactory.get().binaryEncoder(output, null);
    Object datum = reader.read(null, decoder);
    writer.write(datum, encoder);
    encoder.flush();
    return output.toByteArray();
  }
Schema PRIMITIVE = new Schema.Parser().parse("{ \"type\" : \"string\" }");
byte[] b = jsonToAvro("\"" + mystring + "\"", PRIMITIVE);
```

from [How to avro binary encode my json string to a byte array?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/27713583/how-to-avro-binary-encode-my-json-string-to-a-byte-array)